# Regex help in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, text, extract

I need to use regex to extract strings delimited by '/'. I need to extract till the second slash:

for example form the following string:

```
word1 word2/word3 word4 word5/word6/word7 word8 word9
```

The following string:

```
word1 word2/word3 word4 word5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^[^\/]*\/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\//
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code.

```
'http://domain.com/some_path/bla-bla/bla-bla'.match(/(https?|ftp):\/\/([^/]+\/){1,2}/)[0]
=> "http://domain.com/some_path/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\w+:(\/)\1(\w+)\.\w+\1\w+\1
```

Answer (score 2):

hey try this without using regex`

```
'http://domain.com/some_path/bla-bla/bla-bla'.split("/",4).join("/");
```

it'll give what u want.